# How do I tell Mathematica to write numbers on a file without using scientific notation?

Tags: export, formatting, csv-format

I need to write numbers out to a file without using the scientific notation.  How do I tell Mathematica to do that?

This is the code I am using:

```
ExportString[RandomReal[{0, 10^9}, {1, 5}], "CSV"]
```

> ```
> 7.554498937472847e8, 8.890561732721748e8, 3.1844080035953116e8, 6.011904915821908e8, 9.281223697983398e8
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can suppress the exponential format as you like with `ScientificNotationThreshold`, e.g.

```
NumberForm[#, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-5, 9}] & /@ 
 RandomReal[{0, 10^9}, {1, 5}]
```

resp., as you wrote,

```
ExportString[
 NumberForm[#, ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-5, 9}] & /@ 
  RandomReal[{0, 10^9}, {1, 5}], "CSV"]
```

delivers:

```
{580474481., 128820835., 306427380., 712012070., 390581871.}
```